# What does the number after a www[number] uri mean?

Tags: url, web, uri

what does the number after a www[number] uri mean? Does it have any to do with a multi-site setup?

Example:

`http://www2.macleans.ca/2011/09/15/poor-little-rich-m-b-a-s/`
`http://www1.carleton.ca/about/`

What is it's significance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a URL the number ie www2 refers to a host name used to identify a series of closely related websites within a domain. Such websites are 'mirrors 'used for server load balancing. In some cases, the specific hostname is obscured thus creating the appearance that the user is viewing the 'www' subdomain.